# Monad Transformer with recursion

Tags: haskell

when I want to load a bmp file I do this with:

```
loadBMP :: String -> IO Picture
```

If it isn't certain if the given path exists one could do something as follows:

```
saveLoad :: String -> IO Picture
saveLoad str = do
   b <- doesFileExist str
   if b then loadBMP str
        else return Blank
```

Another way could also be; to use monad transformer:

```
saveLoadM :: String -> MaybeT IO Picture
saveLoadM s = do
    b <- lift $ doesFileExist s
    if  b   then do
                p <- lift$ loadBMP s
                return p
            else MaybeT $ return Nothing
```

But how would you deal with a list of files?

```
test ::[String] -> ListT IO Picture
test [] = ListT $ return []
test (x:xs) = do

    b <- lift $ doesFileExist x
    if  b   then do
                p <- lift$ loadBMP x
                return p    -- would yield a simple [p] 
                -- therefore:
                p : test xs -- wrong -> not working
            else test xs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `fmap`.

```
test :: [String] -> IO [Picture]
-- this bit as before...
    if b then do
        p <- loadBMP x
        (p:) <$> test xs
    else test xs
```

But you should not use `doesFileExist` this way. Instead, load the bitmap and catch the exception when the file does not exist; this prevents a race condition.

```
test (x:xs) = do
    imgE <- try (loadBMP x)
    case imgE of
        Right img -> (img:) <$> test xs
        Left err | isDoesNotExistError err -> test xs
                 | otherwise -> throwIO err -- reraise other exceptions
```

If you're okay with extensions, I feel an anonymous case would fit well here.

```
test (x:xs) = try (loadBMP x) >>= \case
    Right img -> ...
    Left err | ...
             | ...
```

Comment: could you specify the topic of the race condition in this specific case a bit further?

Comment: @ThomasMeyer Bad interleaving: your program calls `doesFileExist`; other program deletes the file; your program calls `loadBMP`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `witherable` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/witherable), like this:

```
import Witherable

test :: [String] -> IO [Picture]
test = wither $ \x -> do
    b <- doesFileExist x
    if b then do
             p <- loadBMP x
             return $ Just p
         else return Nothing
```

To get a sense of intuition for what `wither` means, imagine if it were named `mapMaybeM` instead.